# Is there a field size such that it makes perpetual "candy crush"

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle, combinatorial-game-theory

**a.k.a Infinite Candy Crush**

**Background:**
"[Candy Crush Saga](http://candycrushsaga.com/about)" is called a match3, but it has some "special" events that will eliminate all rows, eliminate all "candies" of a particular shape, or even convert all candies of a particular shape into "special events".

When I make a match lower down in the grid, it changes all the rows above it and creates secondary matches or special events.  When I trigger a special event in the lower rows, similar phenomena occurs.

For larger grids there is a higher likelihood of making a match or event.  The events also have higher likelihood of making a match.

**Question**

**Given:** the rules for candy-crush matching or special events ([link](http://candycrush-cheats.com/special-candies/), [link](http://candycrush-cheats.com/special-candy-combinations/)), given a uniformly randomly selected population of in the field, and given an initial move of one of

- (preferred) a horizontal match of 3 identical non-special candies
- (extra credit)an acceptable "activate special" that either matches a striped or wrapped candy by combining it with two appropriately similar non-special candies
- (extra credit)combine two adjacent specials, or
- (extra credit)combines a "sprinkle" with either an adjacent non-special or special.

**Find:** the size of board such that a match or special event in the bottom row sets off a cascade that 
 - Case1: definitely goes for more than 1000 iterations of events
 - Case2: (extra credit) probably or definitely goes indefinitely.

I put "extra credit" because I'm being fun.  I think math is fun, so I am hoping that it is allowed here.

More references:

- http://mitchellrice.com/tag/candy-crush-simulation/

Comment: Hah! Nice question! This is some kind of ramsey theory thing I guess.

Comment: The question seems underspecified. Do you want the cascade to *definitely* go on for the given length, or *probably* go on that long, or what? How is the trigger move chosen? And what kind of distribution are we drawing the initial field state from?

Comment: Running infinitely isn't likely.  Even with only two colors, there is always a chance of a checkerboard grid dropping down.  Getting a count of the 2-color rectangular boards with no 3-in-a-row would be a good first step.

Comment: @EdPegg - after enough matches, the special candies are created which clear/reset the row.  In the game I regularly get sequences of 5 secondary events in a row and a non-zero percent make "specials".  When the row, or column, or 3-rows in each direction are reset then it "resets the geography" in the sense that previously inactive rows can now repeat.   It is a non-binary candy color field, it has like 5-6 types, and that contributes to the behavior.  I seriously expect that if you had a 1000x1000 or 10k by 10k "board" that represents actual rules, then it just might "go" by itself.